# Gnome Shortcut: Failed to execute child process "if" (No such file or directory)

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, gnome-terminal

I tried to write a one-liner to toggle my panel on and off.

```
if [ $(dconf read /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/intellihide) = "false" ]; then dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/intellihide true; else dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/intellihide false; fi
```

Formatted for readability:

```
if [ $(dconf read /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/intellihide) = "false" ];
then
    dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/intellihide true;
else
    dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-panel/intellihide false;
fi
```

It works when run in `zsh` or `bash`, but not when run with a gnome keyboard-shortcut. When I tried to run it with `gnome-terminal -e <command>` it said

> Failed to execute child process "if" (No such file or directory).

Which file/directory is the error message referring to?

Comment: You’ll need a *shell* to run that, e.g. `/bin/sh` or Bash. `if` is (meant to be) a shell builtin. If you try yo execute it as a process, it fails with that message because there’s no executable file called `if` (and there shouldn’t be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems perfectly fine. I had the same problem and after trying out different things I realized it was actually working. This gnome extension works in such a way, that when intellihide is activated the panel only disappears when a window is obstructed by it. Try maximizing a window and running your toggler.